# Laravel Socialite Login Twitter throw error :Missing required parameter [code_verifier]

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, twitter-oauth, laravel-socialite

I'm struggling with Laravel Socialite login with Twitter.  On the call back URL i get the following error :

`` {"message":"Error occuredies","data":"Client error: `POST https:\/\/api.twitter.com\/2\/oauth2\/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:\n{\"error\":\"invalid_request\",\"error_description\":\"Missing required parameter [code_verifier].\"}\n113"} ``

Here is my front-end side code which I have done in Vue.js and the request is then passed to the API (Laravel) which handle the authentication:

```
<v-btn
                    :size="!isSmall ? '40' : '50'"
                    variant="text"
                    style="background: #1c96e8"
                    color="white"
                    icon="mdi-twitter"
                    @click="loginSocial('twitter-oauth-2')"
                  />
```

Here is the Vue method that will be invoked on that button click

````
      axios
        .get(`/gypsy-login/${social_name}`)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          if (response) {
            window.location.assign(response.data.target_url);
          } else {
            window.location.href = "/sign-in";
          }
          console.log(response.data.target_url);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          window.location.href = "/sign-in";
        });
    },```


Now moving to the API Part i have already setup the Twitter-outh-2 client ID , Secret and call back URL in following way 


```TWITTER_CLIENT_ID=someID
TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET=Some Secrect
TWITTER_URL=https://admin.mysite.com/api/gypsy-login/twitter-oauth-2/callback```


These above credentials are then access by the config/service.php file in following way 


``` 'twitter-oauth-2' => [
        'client_id' => env('TWITTER_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('TWITTER_URL'),
    ],```


Now the thing is when someone clicks on that button I'm successfully redirected to Twitter (As you can see in the image below) but when I click on the authorize this app button I get the above-mentioned error.

If you want to check my controller function I can provide it. Any hint/lead will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Already Implemented Laravel Socialite login with Google,Facebook AND LinkedIn with Following Laravel functions. But I don't know where I'm making mistake with Twitter.

Following function is redirecting to the provider
````

````
public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    try {
        return response()->json([
        'target_url' => Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->redirect()->getTargetUrl(),
        ]);
    }catch(\Exception $ex) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Error occured twitter',
            'data' => $ex->getMessage().$ex->getLine()
        ], 500);
    }
}```
````

Following function is handling the call back of the provider. That's where i'm getting the error. I'm not sure why try statement is not being executed.

````
     public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
    {
  
        try {
           
            $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
            
            $environment = env('APP_ENV');
            $currentDate = Carbon::now()->format('d/m/Y');


            if ($environment === 'production') {
                $url = 'https://admin.mysite.com';
            }else {
                $url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000';
            }
            
            if ($provider == 'google' || $provider == 'linkedin-openid' || $provider == 'facebook' || $provider == 'twitter-oauth-2') {
                $gypsyExists = GypsyMaster::where('email_id', $user->email)->first();
                if($gypsyExists) {
                    $gypsyId = $gypsyExists->gypsy_id;
                    $username = $gypsyExists->email_id;
                    $token = $gypsyExists->generateToken($gypsyId, $username);
                    $gypsyExists->token = $token;
                    $gypsyExists->last_login = $currentDate;
                    $gypsyExists->save();
                    return redirect($url.'/?social=' . $provider . '&token=' . $token);
                } else {
                     return redirect($url.'/social-sign-up?social=' . ucwords($provider) . '&token=' . $user->token.'&name='.$user->name.'&avatar='.$user->avatar_original.'&email='.$user->email);

                }
            }


        } catch(\Exception $ex) {

            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Error occuredies',
                'data' => $ex->getMessage().$ex->getLine()
            ], 500);
                
                        }
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

first of all, please read the error response from callback URL this one `Missing required parameter [code_verifier]` from callback response :

```
{"message":"Error occuredies","data":"Client error: `POST https:\/\/api.twitter.com\/2\/oauth2\/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:\n{\"error\":\"invalid_request\",\"error_description\":\"Missing required parameter [code_verifier].\"}\n113"}
```

So, make sure you have pass the `code_verifier` to your handleProviderCallback function when you request to redirect to provider. You're forget to passing `code_verifier` value.

For example :

```
return redirect($url.'/social-sign-up?code_verifier=' . $code_verifier . '&social=' . ucwords($provider) . '&token=' . $user->token.'&name='.$user->name.'&avatar='.$user->avatar_original.'&email='.$user->email);
```

Comment: Well I have implemented your suggestion but still its throwing the same error